# How to search whether a string is a prefix of strings stored in a set?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

```
std::set<std::string> setStrings;

setString.insert("abc");
setString.insert("abcd");
setString.insert("babc");
```

Question> I would like to know how to check whether "bab" is one of the stored string's prefix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you don't want to search the entire set: just use `std::set<std::string>::lower_bound()` and iterate until you find a `std::string` which doesn't have the desired prefix:

```
std::string const prefix("bab");
for (std::set<std::string>::const_iterator it(setStrings.lower_bound(prefix));
     it != setStrings.end() && it->find(prefix) == 0; ++it) {
    std::cout << "prefixed: '" << *it << "'\n";
}
```

If you just want to find if there is one string with the corresponding prefix you can use the condition as in the loop.

Comment: +1 for an answer with better than O(N) complexity. Why anyone would use a linear search with `std::set<>` is beyond me...

Comment: The complexity for finding all strings with a prefix still has the same complexity O(N): the worst case is that all strings have this prefix. However, it is indeed an O(log N) algorithm to find the first string with a prefix.

Comment: Right, the question says "*is one of the stored string's prefix*", so I took that as finding a single element (and all that's needed in your code in that case is a `break`).

Answer (score 7):

Try using a Trie.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: This should really have been the accepted answer. Using std::set for this is just silly.

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways how to do that. This is one of them:

```
std::set<std::string> setStrings;

setStrings.insert("abc");
setStrings.insert("abcd");
setStrings.insert("babc");

std::string prefix("bab");

std::set<std::string>::iterator i;
for (i = setStrings.begin(); i != setStrings.end(); ++i)
{
    if ((*i).compare(0, prefix.length(), prefix) == 0)
        std::cout << *i << " starts with: " << prefix << std::endl;
}
```

This is another way:

```
std::set<std::string>::iterator i;
for (i = setStrings.begin(); i != setStrings.end(); ++i)
{
    if ((*i).substr(0, prefix.length()) == prefix)
        std::cout << *i << " starts with: " << prefix << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Given that `std::set` is sorted, you could do this a lot more efficiently in general.

Comment: True that. To be honest I wasn't thinking about efficiency when I was writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   std::set<std::string> setString;
   setString.insert("abc");
   setString.insert("abcd");
   setString.insert("babc");
   for ( auto &i : setString ){
      std::cout << i << " result: "<< ( i.find("bab")==0) <<std::endl;
   }
```

this is C++11 but `str::find` works the same way in older C++

```
abc result: 0
abcd result: 0
babc result: 1
```

Comment: `find` will succeed only if all characters match!!